# iMovie 4K resolution to Keynote – apparent loss of resolution

Tags: video-quality, mac, imovie

I exported a 4k resolution video from iMovie on my MacBook Pro. I imported it into Keynote in order to crop it. I noticed that upon exporting from Keynote, the resolution of the video was markedly reduced.

In Keynote, I had exported the cropped video using *File → Export To → Movie.* Upon export, the resolution field only gave me *720p, 1080p,* and *Custom.* I clicked on *Custom.* This gave me three compression types: *H.264, Apple ProRes 422,* and *Apple ProRes 4444.* I tried saving the cropped video using each of these three options. However, in each case, the video appeared to be reduced in quality (presumably resolution).

**My question is: How can I crop a 4K video in Keynote and export it without reducing quality/resolution?**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I changed the dimensions to 2160×3840 and exported and the quality was excellent. Hope this helps.